# running xampp + iis (classic asp) on the same local machine

Tags: php, asp, xampp

i've been using classic asp so far (using iis) and i want to start with php (xampp).
is it possible to run both (local) servers at the same time?

i think the problem is that both are pointing to localhost.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Just set up Xampp to use a different port. Say port 4321. Then you'll have IIS on http://localhost/, and Xampp on http://localhost:4321/

Then you can play with Xampp in total isolation from IIS.

If you've already installed Xampp, have a look in the httpd.conf file (in xampp\apache\conf) -- I have:

```
Listen 4242
```

Under the "listen" section at the top. Change that number to whatever port number you want that doesn't clash with anything, then restart Apache using the Xampp control panel.

Answer (score 4):

You will need to configure apache or iis to use a different port.

The instructions below will show you hot to change the TCP port on APACHE.

```
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/bind.html
```

The instruction below will show you how to change the TCP port on IIS.

```
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/149605
```